# Haskell -- "The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression"

Tags: haskell, syntax, io, monads

Like it says in the title: What does `The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression` mean? I ended my `do` block with a `putStrLn` like it shows in several examples I've seen, and i get an error.

Code:

```
main = do args <- getArgs
           file <-readFile "TWL06.txt"
           putStrLn results
```

Comment: check your indentation. make sure all the lines in the block have the same indentation. tabs and spaces are not the same

Comment: If you're working with indent-sensitive languages like Haskell and Python, do make sure that your editor has sane tab settings.  `:set et ts=8 sw=4 sta` or so in Vim.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Most of the time, it's because your code is mis-aligned and compiler assumes that your "do" block ended prematurely (or has extra code that dont really belong there)

Comment: Saved the day! Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Your last line isn't something like `someVar <- putStrLn "hello"`, by any chance, is it? You'll get that error if you try to do a variable binding on the last line, because it's equivalent to `putStrLn "Hello" >>= \someVar ->` — it expects there to be an expression at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Incorrect indentation can lead to this error. Also, is good not to use tabs, only spaces.