# 'do' construct in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, io, monads, do-notation

I'm trying to learn Haskell and want to write a small program which prints the content of a file to the screen. When I load it into GHCi I get the following error:

> The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression

I know this question has be asked already here: [Haskell — “The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016963/haskell-the-last-statement-in-a-do-construct-must-be-an-expression).

Even though my code is very similar I still can't figure out the problem. If anyone could point out the problem to me I'd be very thankful.

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO
import System(getArgs)

main :: IO()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    inh <- openFile $ ReadMode head args
    printFile inh
    hClose inh

printFile :: Handle -> IO ()
printFile handle = do
    end <- hIsEOF handle
        if end
            then return ()
            else do line <- hGetLine handle
                putStrLn line
                printFile handle
```

Comment: Well, have you checked if your indentation is broken (i.e. you have both tabs and spaces)?

Comment: @delnan: I did. I even changed it from tabs to spaces.

Comment: @delnan: It's line 15:4: 'end <- hIsEOF handle'

Comment: use explicit `{ ; }` to never have to worry about this whitespace foolishness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indentation is broken.  These are better:

```
printFile :: Handle -> IO ()
printFile handle = do
    end <- hIsEOF handle
    if end
        then return ()
        else do line <- hGetLine handle
                putStrLn line
                printFile handle

printFile :: Handle -> IO ()
printFile handle = do
    end <- hIsEOF handle
    if end
        then return ()
        else do
            line <- hGetLine handle
            putStrLn line
            printFile handle
```

By having `if` further indented than `end <- hIsEof handle`, it was actually a line continuation, not a subsequent action in the `do`.  Similarly, the fact that you had `putStrLn line` less indented than `line <- hGetLine handle` means that the `do` (inside the `else`) ended there.

Answer (score 4):

There are seveal issues. First, the `if` is indented too far - `end <- ...` is assumed to be the last line of the `do`. Unindent...

next issue comes up. Same error message, only at line 18. This time, line 19 and 20 are not indented deeply enough (they aren't parsed as part of the `do`). Indent (looks nicer anyway, since it all lines up now)... next error message. The good news is, it's not an indentation error this time and the fix is again trivial.

```
test.hs:9:22:
    Couldn't match expected type `([a] -> a) -> [String] -> FilePath'
           against inferred type `IOMode'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `ReadMode head args'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        inh <- openFile $ ReadMode head args
    In the expression:
        do { args <- getArgs;
             inh <- openFile $ ReadMode head args;
             printFile inh;
             hClose inh }
```

The fix is `inh <- openFile (head args) ReadMode`. If you want a more detailed explanation of why/how your version is incorrect, or what the error means, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: I missed that `openFile` bit when skimming.  Seems like you actually plugged it into a compiler :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I need to read up on that dollar sign.

Comment: @Anonymous: It's nothing fancy, in fact it's boringly trivial :) `f $ x = f x`. It's only useful because it has very low priority, so it can replace parens in some situations (i.e. `return $ Foo 1 "bar"` instead of `return (Foo 1 "bar")`).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    inh <- openFile $ ReadMode head args
    printFile inh
    hClose inh
```

But it is probably nicer like this:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    withFile (head args) ReadMode printFile
```

Comment: Even `printFile` could be shortened to `printFile handle = do end <- hIsEof handle; unless end $ hGetLine handle >>= putStrLn >> printFile handle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use explicit bracketing with `{ ; }` to never have to worry about this whitespace foolishness.

```
printFile :: Handle -> IO ()
printFile handle = do {
    end <- hIsEOF handle ;
        if end
            then return ()
            else do { line <- hGetLine handle ;
                putStrLn line ;
                printFile handle }}
```

would have been totally fine (as in, not cause the error).

I/O is dealt with through the special "`do`" language, in Haskell. It should be embraced. That it is actually implemented via monads is an implementational detail.

To clarify: I don't think braces are better, I think they should go together with a nice and consistent indentation. Braces give us nice and immediate visual clues as to the code's structure. Wild indentation will of course be a pointless distraction most of the time. But also, braces give us a guarantee for the working code, and relieve us from the pointless worries of whitespace accidents. They remove this brittleness.

Comment: Seriously? Even if you think braces are better than indentation – that's a minority opinion in the Haskell community. So saying “always use bracketing” is pretty much flamebait. You can say something like, “it's a good idea to try explicit bracketing if you're not completely confident with indentation and getting strange errors, in fact I prefer to always bracket/semicolon my `do` constructs”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks for the feedback, I expounded upon this point in the answer.