# Haskell: The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression

Tags: haskell, syntax, io, monads

Hey, sorry to dump the error message here but I've tried everything I can find and nothing seems relevant.   This code is generating the error:

```
import System.Environment   
import System.Directory  
import System.IO  
import Data.List  

data Node = PathNode String Float Float [String] | NoNode deriving (Show)


main = do
    (filename:args) <- getArgs  
    load filename


load :: String -> IO ()  
load fileName = do
    contents <- readFile fileName  
    let pathStrings = lines contents
        first = head pathStrings
        args = lines first
        path = createNode args
        putStr path


createNode [String] -> Node
createNode (name:x:y:paths) = PathNode name x y paths
createNode [] = NoNode
```

I know its something to do with alignment, but I have aligned all the calls in the 'load' function correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
-A

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513396/problem-with-do-construct-in-haskell

Answer (score 6):

The last line in the `do` expression is indented too far.

Also, you can just write

```
load :: String -> IO ()  
load fileName =
    putStr . createNode . lines . head . lines =<< readFile filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Only errors I can find besides identation are:
in load: putStr expects String, whereas path is of type Node.
in createNode: Pathnode needs x and y to be of type Float, whereas you give Strings.

```
load :: String -> IO ()  
load fileName = do
    contents <- readFile fileName  
    let pathStrings = lines contents
        first = head pathStrings
        args = lines first
        path = createNode args
    putStr $ show path


createNode :: [String] -> Node
createNode (name:x:y:paths) = PathNode name (read x) (read y) paths
createNode [] = NoNode
```

This solves both type errors described by using show and read.